# How can I write this ElseIf as a Case statement in Excel-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Formats each cell in the plotting area according to text in cell, but would like to know how to do the same with a Case statment.

```
For Each Cell In Range("B11:AB200")
    If Cell.Value = ""
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(230, 230, 230) Then
    ElseIf Cell.Value = "tp" Then
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 51, 150)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(170, 170, 170)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
    ElseIf Cell.Value = "ot" Then
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(170, 170, 170)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
    ElseIf Cell.Value = "lu" Then
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(180, 180, 50)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(120, 120, 120)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
    Else
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(120, 120, 120)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
    End If
Next Cell
```

I have tried the following but get a 'type mistmacth'

```
For Each Cell In Range("B11:AB200")
Select Case Range("B11:AB200")
    Case Cell.Value = ""
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(230, 230, 230)
    Case Cell.Value = "tp"
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 51, 150)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(170, 170, 170)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
    Case Cell.Value = "ot"
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(170, 170, 170)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
    Case Cell.Value = "lu"
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(180, 180, 50)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(120, 120, 120)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
    Case Else
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(120, 120, 120)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
End Select
Next Cell
```

Comment: Change the case selector to:  Select Case Cell.Value then change each case statement to e.g. Case Is = "", Case Is = "tp" and so on

Comment: Just to note, "select case" may be more readable than "elseif" but "elseif" has better performance, so if performance is an issue use elseif. Or possibly consider switch.

Comment: Strange, I have tried that  but found the opposite. I used the same arguments in the same order over a block B11:BC1000 (53406 cells) and found the Case statement to be an average of 0.5 sec faster. This was true whether I used fixed values as above or called the value from variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a few tweaks.

```
    For Each Cell In Range("B11:AB200")
Select Case Cell.value
    Case ""
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(230, 230, 230)
    Case "tp"
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(0, 51, 150)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(170, 170, 170)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
    Case "ot"
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 0, 0)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(170, 170, 170)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
    Case "lu"
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(180, 180, 50)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(120, 120, 120)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
    Case Else
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        Cell.Font.Color = RGB(120, 120, 120)
        Cell.Font.FontStyle = "Normal"
End Select
Next Cell
```